# why my content is not centre of a table, I am using \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Bootstrap}}

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn

How to make a word to be at the centre of the several rows?

In my work below, I want my word `Bootstrap` to be at the centre. It seemed like it was on the left hand side.

I used:

```
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Bootstrap}}
```

[image]

My full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
% \begin{center}
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}M*{6}{N}@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}cXcccccc}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\
\cmidrule{4-8}
    & 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Mean}} 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Bias}} 
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error}}}  
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-tailed)}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  
    \\
\cmidrule{7-8}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
\midrule
    Pair 1 
    & \textit{Testing example dataset} (AA) - \textit{Testing puree Example Dataset} (BB) 
    & 44.76\% 
    &  0.19\%  
    & 4.35 
    & 0.001 
    & 36.67\% 
    & 53.33\%\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It **is** centered! But over 5 column, if it should be centered on the line it should cover 4 cols and also need an extra & before it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define eight columns, but the number of columns in the multicolumn row is only seven. If you add a `&` it is correct. It is meaningless to redirect a "RaggedRight" into a `c`-column as you do in the definition of the columns. Either use a `X`-column (see example 2) or use an `l`-columns instead, if you do not need a multiline column (see example 1):

**Example 1**

Here I have reduced you code to an MWE. I assume you want the `X` to be the ragged right column, so I place a `l` column as column 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}Xcccccc}
\toprule
& & & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\   %% Wrong number of columns, and you can extend the mlticol and extend the cmidrile to cover six columns
\cmidrule(l){4-8}
    & 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Mean}} 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Bias}} 
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error}}}  
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-tailed)}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  
    \\
\cmidrule(l){7-8}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
\midrule
    Pair 1 
    & \textit{Testing example dataset} (AA) -- \textit{Testing puree Example Dataset} (BB) 
    & 44.76\% 
    &  0.19\%  
    & 4.35 
    & 0.001 
    & 36.67\% 
    & 53.33\%\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
% \begin{center}
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}M*{6}{N}@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}XXcccccc}  % Changed from c to X, or remove >{} and change to `l`column.
\toprule
 & & & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\   %% Wrong number of columns
\cmidrule{4-8}
    & 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Mean}} 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Bias}} 
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error}}}  
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-tailed)}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  
    \\
\cmidrule{7-8}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
\midrule
    Pair 1 
    & \textit{Testing example dataset} (AA) - \textit{Testing puree Example Dataset} (BB) 
    & 44.76\% 
    &  0.19\%  
    & 4.35 
    & 0.001 
    & 36.67\% 
    & 53.33\%\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sveinung, thanks